# SQL Query Optimization: what is the best approach to use same metric twice in the fact table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, amazon-redshift

I have one dimension table contains business units and employee names as below.

**table**: dim

```
  business  |  emp_name 
 -----------|----------- 
  sales     |  A        
  sales     |  B        
  marketing |  C        
  product   |  D        
  IT        |  E
```

Also, a fact table that contains transactions between employees as below.
**table:** fct

```
  client_emp_name |  provider_emp_name |  value 
 -----------------|--------------------|-------- 
  A               |  C                 |     10 
  C               |  D                 |      5 
  C               |  B                 |     10
```

I would like to write a query to find sum of the values for each business as both clients and providers (including busines units with no transactions)
**desired result**

```
  business  |  provider_total_value |  client_total_value 
 -----------|-----------------------|--------------------- 
  sales     |                    10 |                  10 
  marketing |                    15 |                   0 
  product   |                     0 |                   5 
  IT        |                     0 |                   0
```

What is the best way to structure the SQL query for this case? I have the following query that gives accurate results but I'm not sure if it is the optimum way to solve this problem.

```
With provider as (
    SELECT
        d.business,
        SUM(f.value) as provider_total_value
    FROM fct as f
        right join  dimension as d on d.emp_name = f.provider_emp_name 
    Group by 1
),

client as (
    SELECT
        d.business,
        SUM(f.value) as client_total_value
    FROM fct as f
        right join  dimension as d on d.emp_name = f.client_emp_name 
    Group by 1
)


Select
    p.business,
    COALESCE(p.provider_total_value, 0) as provider_total_value,
    COALESCE(c.client_total_value, 0) as client_total_value
From provider as p
Inner join client as c on c.business = p.business
```

Thank you!

Comment: In the second query your not doing any operation.

Comment: there is only one query with CTE.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide schema for *trades* table as well?

I think the query that you wrote is efficient. To further improve, I would use integer data type for primary key (business) than a character/string data type.

Comment: Thank you for your response, there was a typo and I edited it. Both inner queries go to fct table

Comment: Hi @yl3441, if the answer was useful, could you please upvote it?